# YARN RMStateStore fenced

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am a newbie in Cloudera Manager and Hadoop.  Please kindly provide help for my question.

I tried to use Kerberos authentication last week.  The enabling and disabling were successful.  However, after disabling Kerberos, I found that the ResourceManagers of my environment are always standby.
[Screen capture from cloudera manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04yL8.png)

When i tried to read the log to see what happened, the log showed that 'RMStateStore has been fenced'.
[Screen capture from log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey59H.png)

Is there anyway to solve the problem?  The whole environment is stuck.  If the provided information is not enough, I will try my best to provide more on request.  Thanks.

Comment: Ruka depending on the environment you could just switch off HA for the resource manager which would get you going.

In terms of fixing the issue have you tried this?

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cdh_rn_fixed_in_521.html

Comment: or just running 

`yarn rmadmin  -transitionToActive <ServiceID> -forcemanual`

as per https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue @Ruka